# Exact Corrections to Measured Data in a Paper?

Tags: error, measurement-error, error-propagation

http://fy.chalmers.se/~f7xiz/TIF080/pendulum.pdf

I am really confused by this paper. They make corrections to the value of $g$ from theoretical corrections, but they plug in measured values with actual uncertainties. The thing is though is that their final corrections are exact values, and I don't understand why they can do that. Can someone help me understand how they are finding exact corrections from inexact data?